# How to compile a embedding extractor on Edge TPU Model Compiler?

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, google-coral

## Error when compiling embedded extractor on coral

I am trying to retrain an image classifier on my coral edgeTPU device. Therefore I followed the steps explained on the [Coral's "Retrain an image classification model on-device"  tutorial](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-classification-ondevice/):

### embedded extractor creation

As a matter of fact, I created an embedding extractor tflite file according to the given example:

```
tflite_convert \
--output_file=mobilenet_v1_embedding_extractor.tflite \
--graph_def_file=mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_frozen.pb \
--input_arrays=input \
--output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Logits/AvgPool_1a/AvgPool
```

### Edge TPU Model Compiler upload

I got the file `mobilenet_v1_embedding_extractor.tflite` and uploaded it into the `Edge TPU Model Compiler` . Unfortunately the compiling process does fail and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Something went wrong. Couldn't compile model.

More details
--------------
Start Time     2019-05-02T14:14:53.309219Z
State          FAILED
Duration       5.963912978s
Type           type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.iot.edgeml.v1beta1.CompileOperationMetadata
Name           operations/compile/16259636989695619987
```

From my point of understanding the above mentioned procedure has to be accomplished before the on-device learning with the `classification_transfer_learning.py` script is executed on the raspberryPi + edgeTPU/ devBoard.

*I hope you can give me a hint to solve the problem and thanks in advance.*

## Update May 3 2019

The compling works without any erros, when i use the unmodified `mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite` model.

I used the [quantized model](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_08_02/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tgz) from [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that some flags for the tflite_convert is missing. We will fix on the website asap. Please try:

```
tflite_convert \
--output_file=mobilenet_v1_embedding_extractor.tflite \
--graph_def_file=mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_frozen.pb \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_dev_values=128 \
--input_arrays=input \
--output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Logits/AvgPool_1a/AvgPool
```

It is to indicate that you'd like to convert to a quantization model,which is the only valid format for the edgetpu converter yet. With these flags, it should work fine.